# Inherit python logger from parent function scope

Tags: python, logging

I want my function `do_x` to use (child) logger `__main__.do_all` that is defined in the parent scope `do_all` from which `do_x` is called. Instead the root logger is used by default.

Is there a way do force `do_x` to use the child logger `__main__.do_all`? Should I pass the logger as parameter to `do_x`, even though it is not recommended in numerous posts? Assume that I want to call `do_x` also from other scopes using other (child) loggers.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def do_x():
    logger.warning('doing x')

def do_all():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.do_all')
    logger.warning('Starting do_all')
    do_x()

def do_all_other():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.do_all_other')
    logger.warning('Starting do_all_other')
    do_x()

do_all()
do_all_other()
```

Produces

```
2022-09-27 11:34:40,562 - __main__.do_all - do_all - WARNING - Starting do_all
2022-09-27 11:34:40,562 - __main__ - do_x - WARNING - doing x
2022-09-27 11:34:40,562 - __main__.do_all_other - do_all_other - WARNING - Starting do_all_other
2022-09-27 11:34:40,562 - __main__ - do_x - WARNING - doing x
```

I want the second and the last line of the output to use `__main__.do_all` and `__main__.do_all_other` respectively

Comment: `do_x()` will need to know where it is called from. There is only two ways: pass the name of the parent as a param, or inspect the stack

Comment: No logger is really defined *in* the function. The call `getLogger` returns (creating if necessary) a specific logger instance that is managed by the `logging` module, regardless of where the call to `getLogger` is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import logging
import inspect

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def do_x():
    logger_name = __name__ + '.' + inspect.stack()[1].function
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.warning('some log')

def do_all():
    do_x()

def do_other():
    do_x()


do_all()
do_other()
```

produces

```
2022-09-26 17:33:06,967 - __main__.do_all - do_x - WARNING - some log
2022-09-26 17:33:06,967 - __main__.do_other - do_x - WARNING - some log
```

Requires a recent version of python, but works with older versions too. `inspect.stack()` just returns the data in a slightly different format in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

The logger namespace is independent of function scopes. `do_x` should simply make the same call to `getLogger` to use the same `Logger` instance.

```
def do_x():
    logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.do_all').info('doing x')
```

Comment: It does not solve for possibility of "calling `do_x` from other scopes using other loggers". I updated the question a bit to illustrate this issue. Think of `do_x` as a general function called by various parent functions. Though thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why do you want to use the same logger if you want different output it?

Comment: I do not want to use same logger, I want exactly the opposite in fact. I was hoping that `logger` variable (is it variable?) in `do_x` can point to the `Logger` instance in the functions' parent scope, depending from where `do_x` is called.

At the same time I want to keep the code for `do_x` general enough so that I do not have to edit it each time I add a new call with a new logger. Let's say that `do_x` is some simple transformation of data and I want to log some intermediary results on the way.